# Identity Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have an expression:
$${x}^2 +5{x} +6$$

This can be factored to:
$$({x} +2)({x}+3)$$

So,
$${x}^2 +5{x} +6 = ({x} +2)({x}+3)$$

This is an identical equation. And it is true for all values we substitute in $x$.

**Why is it true for all values we substitute in $x$?**

> **More generally, why an identity equation is an equation that is always true for any value substituted into the variable??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> More generally, why an identity equation is an equation that is always true for any value substituted into the variable??

Because the rules that justify the identity (associativity, distributivity) also work for numbers. So the exact same operations you did to justify the factorization can be done when you replace $x$ with any number.